# How do I read the contents of a serialize form sent by a ajax call to a controller in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

Using MVC 3

I have a button that saves a mvc questionare form. The form will have 50 or more questions with user answers. I decided to serailize the form instead of placing the answers in a array to send to the controller. Not sure how to read the form and grab the question Id and the answers?

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Question/SaveQuestionaire',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#SignupForm").serialize(), // creates an object for you
```

View:

```
@using COPSGMIS;
@model IEnumerable<COPSGMIS.Models.Quiz>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Questionaire";
}
<h2>Questionaire</h2>
  <input type="hidden" id="currentstep" name="currentstep" />
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Questionaire", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SignupForm" }))
   {
       <div id="wizardtemplate">       
            @foreach (var step in Model)       
            {
              <fieldset class="wizard">
                <div class="page_Title"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => step.Title)</div>               
                @foreach (var question in step.Results)
                {
                ... code removed ....
                <label for="question">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => question.NumberedQuestion)</label>  
                 @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayControl(question.QuestionID, question.Choices, question.AnswerValue,question.ControlType)) 
                 </div>                               
                 @Html.Partial("_Comment", question)
               <hr />
                }
              </fieldset>
            }
```

HTML RENDERED:

```
<label for="question">3. This is a sample question (2) for the questionare?</label>  
                 <div class='answer'><input type='date' id='3' name='3' value='2012-12-10' /></div> 
                 </div>                               
 ... code removed ....

 <label for="question">4. This is a sample question (3) for the questionare?</label>  
                 <div class='answer'><input type='text' id='4' name='4' value='999' /></div> 
                 </div>
```

Model:

```
 public class Quiz
    {
        public int ReviewID { get; set; }
        public int StepID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

I need help with

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveQuestionaire(int reviewid, Serialized? form)
.... code here
```

**UPDATED CODE**PLEASE LOOk HERE

My Ajax CALL:

```
function saveQuestioniare() {
           alert('Here');
           $.ajax({
            url: '/Question/SaveQuestionaire',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {reviewid: 8, col:$("#SignupForm").serialize()},
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
            success: function (json) {
                alert("hERE!");
            }
        });
    }
```

MY Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveQuestionaire(int? id, FormCollection col)
        {
            using (var db = new NexGenContext())
            {
                foreach (var key in col.AllKeys.Where(q => !q.Contains("Comment_")))
                {
                    var answer = col[key];
                    int questionId = Convert.ToInt32(key);
                    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                            "EXEC SP_AddUpdateResponse @QuestionID, @Reviewer, @AnswerValue, @ReviewID",
                            new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", questionId),
                            new SqlParameter("@Reviewer", "TEST - CG"),
                            new SqlParameter("@AnswerValue", answer),
                            new SqlParameter("@ReviewID", id)
                        );
                }
            }
            return Json("save", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Question/SaveQuestionaire',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {model:$("#SignupForm").serialize()},
```

and on the server side

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveQuestionaire(int? reviewid, IList<Quiz> model)
```

or the old school way of getting the posted form values in `FormCollection`

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveQuestionaire(int? reviewid, FormCollection col)
```

Comment: i really doubt the internal server error is because of the above mentioned suggestions, anyhow have you tried debugging the code by pacing a debugger at the start of your action result and then stepping through the code using `f10` or `f11`

Comment: ok my bad the server error is because probably the `reviewid` is null, try setting it `int? reviewid` or `string reviewid`...

Comment: I added the reviewid, but its not making it into the controller? Using Chrome dev tools, I get the following Request: URL:http://localhost:52089/Question/SaveQuestionaire
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: how did you added the reviewid ? can you update the question to reflect the changes you made? is it some thing like `data:{reviewid:1,model:$("#SignupForm").serialize()},` ? have you placed the debugger ? just make the `int` nullable to make sure the post action method has been called.

Comment: data sent: reviewid:8
col:Comment_1=&2=Test8&Comment_2=&3=2012-12-02&Comment_3=&4=Test8&Comment_4=&5=Test8&Comment_5=&6=Answer1&Comment_6=&7=Test8&Comment_7=&8=Test8&Comment_8=&9=Test8&Comment_9=&10=Test8&Comment_10=&11=111&Comment_11=&12=2222&Comment_12=&13=333&Comment_13=&14=4444&Comment_14=&15=5555&Comment_15=&16=6666&Comment_16=&17=7777&Comment_17=&18=8888&Comment_18=&19=9999&Comment_19=&20=9999&Comment_20=&21=111&Comment_21=&22=2222&Comment_22=&23=3333&Comment_23=&24=4444&Comment_24=&25=666666&Comment_25=

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22343/discussion-between-chaka-and-3nigma)

Comment: please have a closeer look at your code as POST params you are sending `reviewid` and in the actionresult you are recieving the **id** change either of them and you are good to go